# Error in finding NavHostFragment Jetpack Navigation Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-navigation, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation

I am using Jetpack Navigation for handling the navigation of Fragments. After following the documentation, when I run the app I am getting the below error.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
```

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
compileSdkVersion 'android-P'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.meditab.imspatient"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {

def nav_version = "1.0.0-alpha01"

implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.0' // Constraint layout

implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version" // Kotlin

// Anko
implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-commons:$anko_version" // Anko Commons
implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-design:$anko_version" // For SnackBars
implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-coroutines:$anko_version" // Anko Coroutines

// Support libraries
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0-alpha1' // Support v4
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-alpha1' // AppCompat
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0-alpha1' // RecyclerView
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-alpha1' // Design Support library
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0-alpha1' // CardView

// Jetpack Navigation
implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$nav_version"
implementation "android.arch.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$nav_version"

// Dagger 2
implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.14.1'
kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.14.1'
provided 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'

// Retrofit, OkHttp, OkHttpInterceptor and GSON
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.10.0'

implementation 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4' // Material EditText
 }

kotlin {
experimental {
    coroutines "enable"
}
}
```

**Code of the Activity hosting the NavHostFragment**

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_page)

// Handle the clicks for bottom navigation view
bottom_navigation_view_homepage_activity.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener { item ->


    when (item.itemId) {
        R.id.action_appointment -> findNavController(item.itemId).navigate(R.id.appointmentFragment)

        R.id.action_chat -> findNavController(item.itemId).navigate(R.id.chatFragment)
    }



}

Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.appointmentFragment)
```

}

**Activity's XML file**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
       />
    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation_view_homepage_activity"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/nav_item_color_state"
        app:itemTextColor="@drawable/nav_item_color_state"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_view" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I have implemented the Navigation Graph properly. Also, the project is refactored to AndroidX.

Comment: AS 3.2 Canary 15 is available now, check if it fixes your problem

Answer (score 6):

If this issue happens while using a release build, chances are that the class name has been minified by proguard. That way, the reference `android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"` in the XML file will not match any valid class.

Try to add this line in the proguard file

```
-keepnames class androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment
```

so that the class name does not get minified and that it stays as mentionned in the XML file.

Answer (score 0):

Try to call `Navigation.findNavController(bottom_navigation_view_homepage_activity, R.id.appointmentFragment)`

You also don't need to set `setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener`, just edit your navigation graph "nav_graph" as follow:

```
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/action_appointment"
        ..../>
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/action_chat"
        ..../>
```

Basically set your fragment id in nav_graph same as the item ids in your bottom nav view.

Comment: any idea about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63052712/nested-fragment-backpress-child-inside-parent-have-problem

Answer (score 0):

Please check if your 'id_menu' called in BottomNavigation is the same as 'id_fragment' in the Navigation Graph.

You can use this method to navigate 'bottom_nav' to show a fragment:

```
setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

    navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.main_fragment)
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(bottom_nav,navController)
    NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController)
```

and don't forget to overide the following method:

```
override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
    return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController,null)
}
```

Please let me know if this code works for you.

As an aside, with Kotlin you don't need call findViewById, you might find benefit by implementing DataBinding in your layout.

Comment: have any idea how to do this with this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63052712/nested-fragment-backpress-child-inside-parent-have-problem

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the fragment dependency?
implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment:1.2.0" this is for java i don't know if it's the same for kotlin